# displaying divs inside form fields in same line

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

- can you tell me how to how to make divs inside form to align
- providing code below
- display: table-cell not working
  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EKwOKa

  ```
  <div class="form-fields">
      <label>Name:</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="stored" value="" /><br>

      <label>Email:</label>
      <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="stored" value="" /><br>

      <label>Message:</label>
      <textarea name="message" id="message" class="stored"></textarea><br>
  </div>

  <div class="upload-image">
      <div class="upload-image-preview"></div>
      <input type="file" name="file" value="Upload Image" />
  </div>
  ```

Comment: you should update your previous question with this, not start a new question - with your next problem

Comment: which `div` ? `upload-image-preview` ?

Comment: @pedram this two <div class="form-fields"> and <div class="upload-image">

Comment: @Omarjmh people told me not to ask so many questions in sam equestion

Comment: @all why did you guys marked it negative...since I tried

Comment: Okay, it's already side by side,  I still don't understand what you trying to do? want to move it below? or like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/L7ayp0qg/) ?

Answer (score 0):

`vertical-align: top;` will help top alignment.

```
.form-fields {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```